# Going back to using a fluent method after using a fluent method of a public property in PHP?

Tags: php

Going back to using a fluent method, after using a fluent method of a public property in PHP?

I use PHP.7.4 and use fluid setters.

```
$clientList =(new ClientList)
->filter->setId('222')
->get();//Here I want to reuse methods from the class and not from the filter property
```

```
$objClientList = new ClientList();
$objClientList->filter->setId('222');
$clientList = $objClientList->get();//Works fine
```

I use pure PHP, I have this structure:

```
trait BuilderClient
{
    protected $field1;

    public function setField1(int $field1): self
    {
        $this->field1 = new Field();
        //Encapsulated
        return $this;
    }

}

class FilterClient{
    use BuilderClient;
    use Filter;
}

class ClientList
{
    public $filter;

    public function getList(): array
    {
        //build list
        return $clientList;
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->filter = new FilterClient();
    }
}
```

Greetings!

Comment: Fluent methods aren't a feature of the language as such, they're just a coding pattern. So the details of how they work is entirely up to the author of the class implementing that pattern. If this is your own class, you need to show us how you've implemented it; if it's a third-party library, you need to at least tell us which library, and make sure you've checked their documentation.

Comment: Yes of course, I have updated the question giving more details.

Comment: Simply speaking - you can't, without introducing a variable and saving an intermediate object in it. Exactly as you've shown in the second code snippet. There is no way to "fork" execution of an expression.